# Get wikipedia city info

Tags: java, android, api, rest, wikipedia-api

Get city information from wikipedia, and show it on an Android APP.

However, every time I try to transform the data to JSON, throws an exception

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Threadless&rvprop=content&format=json&rvsection=0

```
url = new URL("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Threadless&rvprop=content&format=json&rvsection=0");
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
String line ="";
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    sb.append(line);
}
JSONObject city;
JSONArray jsondata = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
city = jsondata.getJSONObject(0);
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with cities and it's missing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The Web Service does not return a JSON array, but a JSON Object containing an Array. Try using a `JSONObject` instead.

```
JSONObject jsondata = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this...

```
JSONObject searchJson = new JSONObject(Content);
                JSONObject queryObject = searchJson.getJSONObject("query");
                JSONArray searchObject = queryObject.getJSONArray("search");
                JSONObject titObject = (JSONObject) searchObject.get(0);
```